# Swap Gridfieldmanager on button click

Tags: blackberry, horizontalfieldmanager

I have an application that I am building for blackberry OS 6.

I have a screen made of a Gridfieldmanager and a Horizontalfieldmanager. The Horizontalfieldmanager contains 4 image buttons along the bottom, when these are clicked I want to basically swap the Gridfieldmanager with another fieldmanager. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is! You can use `theManager.replace(Field oldField, Field new Field)` to swap them out.

[Documentation on replace](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#replace%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29)